# Copy/Paste Text From The Tool-tip Of Google Sheets Cell

Tags: database, web-scraping, google-sheets, screen-scraping

I want to capture the tooltip text of the URLs that Google sheet shows.

I've this link in the Google sheet:
https://www.vingle.net/

When I hover over this URL, this text is shown:
Create an account or log in - Vingle is an interest-based community platform available via mobile and web, where users can connect with people who love what they love!

Like this:

[image]

This is what I want to do:
Copy whatever text is shown in the popup/tooltip of the URL and paste it in the cell next to it. From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

FYI, this is actually the meta tag. Most of you might offer IMPORT functions but the I don't want to use import function for some reason. I just want the text that Google sheet is already capturing. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to get exactly whatever link details are given when hovering over a link in sheets. Why you don't want to use `IMPORT` functions? Another option could be to use Apps Script's [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). What do you think of this?

Comment: I don't want scrape anything outside of the sheet that's the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

> Copy whatever text is shown in the popup/tooltip of the URL and paste it in the cell next to it.

I do not think that can be done in Google Sheets. There are no methods in the Sheets API nor in SpreadsheetApp to capture contents of a pop-up info panel. You would have to retrieve the meta tag through an `importdata()` formula or a script that uses [UrlFetchApp()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).