# Can we get the tooltip text from Google Sheets #ERROR! cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a function to fetch file schema using Drive.Files.get(file id).
It works correctly when run through extensions menu or from apps script dashboard.
But when used as a function to get the property value for specific file id, from sheets, as formula, it shows an error that an API key is not available. All this is fine.

My question is if any such errors occur, the description can be seen when you hover mouseover the cell. (see image below).

**Can we capture this error description?**

[tooltip on #ERROR! cell in google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux4xa.png)
[using function as formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omYVO.png)

```
    function GetFilePropertyMimeType(fId) {
      console.log("3. fetching mimetype for: %s",fId);
      return Drive.Files.get(fId).mimeType;
    };
```

```
            fSchema.trashingUser,
            fSchema.downloadUrl
          ]];
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log("Error in getting file for id: "+fId+" -- %s", 
    err.message);
          ss.getRange("C"+i).setValue(321.123);
          continue;
        } finally {  
        }
        targetSheet.getRange(parseInt(i),3,1,21).setValues(rowData);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
```

I tried capturing error.type. It returns 8 which means "all other types" other than specifics described from 1 to 7.

The requirement is such that, the users of this sheet should be notified of such errors, if occurred.
As of now, I am notifying some description based on error.type.

[Copy/Paste Text From The Tool-tip Of Google Sheets Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369203/copy-paste-text-from-the-tool-tip-of-google-sheets-cell) is somewhat related to this but the implementation doesn't match the requirement. Kindly help me understand if I am missing something on this.

Where error description is available, as in this case, it is so sensible to provide description than mentioning bland "some unknown error" kind of...

I have added a task in my WBS to manually verify such errors and type in the description. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I thought that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75925161

Comment: Yes. Looks like it. I will execute and confirm. Thanks @Tanaike.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply wrap your code in a try catch block.

```
function GetFilePropertyMimeType(fId) {
  try {
    console.log("3. fetching mimetype for: %s",fId);
    return Drive.Files.get(fId).mimeType;
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err.message;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. 
This I have tried. Json exception is not handled by apps script. It throws a pop-up with exception description and stops the execution.
One more also tried. To circumvent the error, I am pushing a known hard-code custom.error.type and introducing a blank finally block to let the process continue. 
But this is not preferred approach. Hope I could convey it clearly.

Comment: added the lines of code in edits. Kindly see.